# TCHAR and _tprintf under Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos

I am playing around with clucene under mac osx with xcode and have some problems with the demo application, maybe someone can help me with that :-)

The demo code comes with 'document' and 'query' arrays:

```
const TCHAR* docs[] = {
  _T("a b c d e"),
  ...
  _T("a c e a b c"),
  NULL
};

const TCHAR* queries[] = {
  _T("a b"),
  ...
  _T("\"a c e\""),
  NULL
};
```

which are used for indexing and as queries which work good as long as i comment out the _tprintf lines like:

```
_tprintf(_T("Query: %s\n"), qryInfo);
```

so _tprintf seems to be unrecognized by my system and if I use tprintf xcode says there is no matching function for call to tprintf.

So how do I print TCHARs correctly? CLucene needs TCHAR names for Fields.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is Windows code isn't it?  The `_T` is used to allow both UNICODE and ISO-8859-x characters used in the same source file (Microsoft specific).

Comment: I think you are right. But TCHAR works fine on osx shouldn't there be some way of printing thous types?

Comment: If TCHAR works it's because the demo code or clucene or something defines it. TCHAR isn't defined by OS X's libraries and shouldn't be used except to avoid having to edit a lot of ported Windows code. (And I'd argue TCHAR should be avoided on Windows as well. We're long past the point where there's value in writing both UNICODE and non-UNICODE programs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Windows, `TCHAR` is either `wchar_t` or plain `char` depending on your project settings.

Likewise, `_tprintf` is either `wprintf` of `printf` to match the choice of characters.

On OSX you will likely have to make this choice yourself, perhaps

```
#define _tprintf    wprintf
```

Comment: Hm this returns 'a' for _T("a b") and _T("a c") but nothing for _T("\"a b\""). How does the proper way looks like to return the whole sequence?

Comment: ok with the %ls format specifier _tprintf(_T("Query: %ls\n"), qryInfo); prints 'a c' for _T("a c") but for _T("\"a c\"") it prints '"a c"~4' what does ~4 mean?

Answer (score 1):

TCHAR is a Windows character type.  On non-Windows platforms, Clucene defines the TCHAR type and related functions in [config/repl_tchar.h](http://clucene.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/clucene/trunk/src/CLucene/config/repl_tchar.h?revision=2088&view=markup).

Either that header is not being included, or the project is misconfigured.

Comment: Ok in this case my project / build of clucene is misconfigured i don't have that header file or even the folder config.

Comment: also the version installed via port doesn't provide that file. so how do i build a correct version of clucene under mac osx?